# Shrinking size of Y chromosomes

Tags: evolution, chromosome, human-evolution

I read on the web that the size of Y chromosomes decreased in earlier period of time and the picture below tells that it is still occurring.

So basically I want to know what caused  this shrinking and if it has stopped now then what caused this break ??

[image]

Comment: you can find at least the beginnings of the answer on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_chromosome#Degeneration

Comment: @Ben Bolker what about the second part ?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. As a new user, you should finish reading the [tour]. Please do not post text as graphics, which discriminate against people with visual deficiencies and which cannot be indexed. Rewrite it as text.